# What kind of camera could work inside a microwave?

Tags: temperature, camera, microwave, damage, radiation

I want to record video inside a microwave, is it possible?

What if it was hid behind a shield or the same galvanized material as the door? The detailed structure may completely ruin visibility tho

Comment: *galvanized material as the door* The door of a microwave oven isn't "galvanized", there's a metal mesh with holes no larger than a certain size so that the microwaves stay in but light can pass through. What happens to metal objects inside a microwave oven? Can the extremely delicate electronics in a camera handle that you think?

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant. It seems really difficult/impossible but worth discussing for me imo.

Comment: There are two broad approaches that come immediately to mind. One is to use a light pipe. Quartz would be okay, but only has an acceptance angle of about 30 degrees. Sapphire is twice that, at about 60 degrees. The second thought is probably better, where you use a Fourier plane filter to remove the screen between your camera and what you're filming. That's a post processing step and the software isn't difficult. But it is mathy. Look up "spatial filtering" in an optics book.

Comment: That is an interesting tech, it doesn't seem to be giving video tho. More for analyzing some colors. My research shows that light pipes won't be recording actual video and spatial filtering also wouldn't provide realtimeish video of the contents. Am I wrong? if so, i'll research more

Comment: Anything can be done in real time (or a small delay, at least) if you have enough processing power.

Comment: Can you get video similar to that of a camera?  This looks like the extent of it: https://youtu.be/79f03Dj_mpI?t=235

Comment: IMO just bore a small hole in the inner casing of the oven, then put a pinhole camera in the outer side, the EM won't escape if the hole is much smaller than wavelength.

Comment: @tigertiger Think "fish eye" when considering sapphire. I used it to video the explosion event inside a car cylinder while running. So yes, you can use sapphire. It's just not COTS. Also, you can most certainly use spatial filtering, Fourier domain, to post process your video and remove the screen. How well you can do that will depend on the applied filter. But there is nothing fundamentally wrong with the approach. Hecht and Zajac would be my go-to textbook here.

Comment: @jonk I appreciate the response! Am a new grad mech engg so I can learn but have questions. Were you able to get video similar to that of a digital camera? My goal is to be able to identify various digital features while the microwave is running real time

Also what is COTS? google didn't turn up anything with COTS and light pipes

Comment: @tigertiger COTS = "commercial, off the shelf". No, the video wasn't like a modern digital camera. This was 25 years ago. Stuff was harder back then. For spatial filtering, you really do need to spend a little time with Hecht & Zajac or something similar. It is something wonderful to behold. Impressive results are achievable with some work. Perhaps you might consider contacting the physics department of a local university. They should be able to get you started.

Comment: thanks @Jonk This seems far more complicated as there is far more to the project than recording. Going to keep this in mind but search for more simple solutions. Not sure why my questions are getting downvoted :/

Comment: @tigertiger It's not me downvoting you. And don't worry about it. Different strokes for different folks and it's often nothing personal. (It can't be -- they don't know you from Adam.) I think you would be impressed with the simplicity of the ideas of the Fourier plane and how it works to achieve the results I think you want. You really should check out Hecht & Zajac or else look up "image enhancement" together with "spatial filtering". Hecht & Zajac provide a really wonderful set of example cases in their book on Optics. Worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, if you have proper resources.
You can make an opening for endoscope in one of the walls, i've seen videos made this way. But i don't recommend it - you are breaching oven's shield this way, which is dangerous.

Comment: mhmm, can do that if it is inside the microwave cube, and then a small hole is just a size of the already holed wall for the endoscope. That would not expose a user to any extra radiation either. What do you think?
Side from the edge of the endoscope tube, the rest of it would be behind the walls of cube anyways

Comment: I saw the video filmed inside the microwave once, author said that he made it with endoscope. Can't tell you anything else. Most ovens have ventilation holes, you can try push endoscope through it.

Comment: I appreciate it! Cheers 

The microwave wavelenght is about 12cm so seems viable. Would need to create a robust cheap enoscope tho

Answer (score 0):

Microwave camera is nothing new as an idea. There are some purely practical limitations. Some of them:

1. Things emit not especially much microwaves. Thermal noise is what they give and that unfortunately exists also in receivers and will totally cover the tiny amounts that can be catched from the radiation. Cooling to a few kelvins helps, but it will be incovenient. A more practical idea is to take a high power microwave illumination lamp. That's a radio transmitter and the idea is used in radars.
2. For some resolution you need  pixels like the photosensitive pixels in the image sensor of the camera. They must all be antennas which have everyone own receiver. The antennas must have some size, at least 1 mm diameter if you have say 1 cm wavelength. One megapixel sensor can be quite tall and wide and the receivers also need some room. The sensor will make your camera quite heavy and big, but not impossible. The sensor is only about one square meter with 1 mm pixels.
3. Imaging needs a lens. That's no theoretical problem. Insulator materials refract also microwaves. The lens cannot be of normal photo camera lens size. It must have diameter which is  proportioned to the wavelength in the same way as photo camera lenses are proportioned to average light wavelength about 600 nanometers. If you reduce the demand of resolution enough you can easily work well with a say 50 meters wide lens. keeping it hidden is a challenge, so something else should be thought. One possibility is to use holography. That's well possible because you already must have a radio transmitter for illumination. Only make the transmitter to produce pure enough sinewave. In holography no lens is needed, only dense enough plate of antennas.

4. It can happen that the walls and door reflect substantial amount of your illumination. You must have something which makes for you a possibility to separate distances, too. Pulse radar idea is one possibility but your pulses must be quite short. If you use 1 cm wavelength the pulses must contain say 10 cycles so the distance resolution is only 10 cm. But that can be enough for something. For better resolution make the wavelength shorter. Frequency sweeping techniques are another possibility but the needed signal processing is astronomical when compared to pulse radar idea. And the distance resolution vs wavelength ratio stays.

Hopefully you got somethig from these vague sentences. If you still haven't master of sc. level knowledges of electronics, radio techniques and signal processing you very likely need some pro help for the design. And you need it too for the practical construction.

Comment: I think you misunderstood "recording video inside a microwave"  with "recording video with mircowaves".

Comment: If that's true then doing something inside a microwave is a kind of doing that I'm not familiar with. I have heard and believed that microwave is a radiowave which has wavelength 1mm...30cm, it's not made of any material. As well the questioner could dream of a home made movie which will have an artistic name or subject named "inside a microwave".

Comment: Taking video of noodles inside your microwave is not as exciting. Using microwaves to create video (radar) is something completely different.

Comment: So it was an artistic name, No problem, me and surely many others are here only for leisure time fun.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, the other guys are right. Looking to record inside a microwave!

If i was to use a pinhole/endoscope inside do you the the microwaves would ruin the electronics inside the camera eventually?